# How to set initial value of Star Rating widget from server

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the Star Rating widget and I'm trying to set the initial value of the widget from the value I get back from the server.  I know the principle is to set the default option to `selected` but I can't figure out how.  Some widgets have an `setDefault` method, but not this one, so there must be another way.

Any help would be awesome.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="stars_content" style="padding-top:6px;">
            <select id="ContentRating" name="ContentRating">
                <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
                <option value="2">Poor</option>
                <option value="3">OK</option>
                <option value="4">Good</option>
                <option value="5">Very Good</option>
            </select>
            <span id="content_hover" style="padding-left:5px;"></span>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$("#stars_content").stars({
        inputType: "select",
        captionEl: $('#content_hover')
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it manually

```
$("#stars_content option[value=3]").attr("selected",true);
```

that should do it.

EDIT

it appears this [widget's API](http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/htm/star-examples.htm?b44) provides a parameter for this

```
$("#stars-wrapper1").stars("select", 1); // select first Star (see element Value in HTML source)
```

So your code would be

```
$("#stars_content").stars({
    inputType: "select",
    captionEl: $('#content_hover'),
    select:3
});
```

... I think

Comment: I would have thought that would work too, but it doesn't.  I figured I must have misunderstood the usage, as the explanation on the site is ambiguous.  Thank you though!

Comment: You got me on the right track and with some persistance I got it working with `$("#stars_content").stars("select", parseInt({{ program.ContentRating }}));
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are getting the "selected rate" from server, but suppose its via `$.get`, and the rate number is saved to var `selected_rate`, than you could do something like:

```
var selected_rate = 3; //supposing its 3 ('OK')
$('#stars_content option[value=' + selected_rate + ']').attr('selected', true)
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that '#stars_content' is just a div.  So it won't have options, right?  The id that I have set for the select elem gets overwritten by the widget.  Aarrrggghh!